# solution to towers of Hanoi problem

Tags: algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

how do i solve for running time in the towers of Hanoi problem. I get a recurrence realation like t(n) = 2t(n-1) + 1. After drawing the recursion tree i get at every step values like 1+2+4+8... the height of the tree will be lg(n). how do i calculate the sum of the series? when do i stop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you get at each level of the recursion tree is a power of 2.  Hence, the sum is: `2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^{n-1}`.

That's a geometric sum: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Let `S(n) = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^{n-1}`.  Then: `S(n) - 2*S(n) = 1 - 2^n`

And finally: `S(n) = 2^n - 1`.

Comment: You can find that out by trying with small cases.  For `n = 1` you get `2^0`.  For `n = 2`, `2^0 + 2^1`.  So the highest exponent is `n-1`, not `n`.

Comment: @user265260: Mr. Cooper has the correct sum.  Think of it this way: what is the largest value an unsigned integer with n bits can represent?  That is different than the number of values that n bits can represent since 0 is one of those values.

Comment: i think i am wrong in stating that height is `lg(n)`, it should be `n`. Could someone tell me which is right

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi? You have everything in there.

Comment: @user265260: You never specified. Don't get snarky at answers given because your question wasn't well-stated.

Comment: @user265260: apparently you hadn't looked at the wikipedia article, because the answer to your question is in there.